# CSS code doesn't stylize horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have this code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-image:url('');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:5px;
    height:0px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#ecedee
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color:#6dc0c8;
}
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color:#56999f;
}
    ::-webkit-resizer{
    background-image:url('');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:4px;
    height:0px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 4px;
}
```

It perfectly stylizes vertical scrollbars but doesn't work on horizontal scrollbars.

I am trying to stylize horizontal scrollbar in this chart:
[image: Chart]

Comment: Can you provide minimal level working code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 4px; // Apply height of horizontal scrollbar
}